# Pandas - retain rows that match two cells in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
    trial  id  run        rt  acc
0       1   1    1  0.941836    1
1       2   1    1  0.913791    1
2       3   1    1  0.128986    1
3       4   1    1  0.155720    0
4       1   1    2  0.414175    0
5       2   1    2  0.699326    1
6       3   1    2  0.781877    1
7       4   1    2  0.554666    1
```

There are 2 runs per id, and 70+ trials per run. Each row contains one trial. So the hierarchy is id - run - trial.

I want to retain only runs where mean acc is above 0.5, so I used `temp = df.groupby(['id', 'run']).agg(np.average)` and `keep = temp[temp['acc']] > 0.5` .

Now I want to remove all trials from runs that are not in keep.

I tried to use `df[df['id'].isin(keep['id'])&df['run'].isin(keep['run'])]`, but this doesn't seem to work correctly. df.query doesn't seem to work either as the indices and columns differ between the dataframes.
Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to retain only runs where mean acc is above 0.5

Using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), you can use a single Boolean series for indexing:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['id', 'run'])['acc'].transform('mean') > 0.5]
```